# (powershell) Select-String vs Findstr

Tags: powershell, findstr, select-string

This is very simple... why first command working and second no?

Findstr looks to me for best use in "dos"like commands and not in powershell.

```
Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | findstr ^DisplayName

Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | Select-String -pattern "DisplayName"
```

powershell newbie :)

Comment: `Get-AppXProvisionPackage -online |Select-Object DisplayName`

Comment: so Select-Object it is :) thanks

Comment: another option is passing the output as string stream, then searching for it.
`Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -pattern "DisplayName"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`findstr` is an operating system executable (`findstr.exe` actually), which you can see from within PowerShell:

```
Get-Command findstr
```

Output:

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                   
> -----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                   
> Application     findstr.exe                                        10.0.10... C:\WINDOWS\system32\findstr.exe
> ```

`Select-String` is similar but more powerful and is a native PowerShell cmdlet

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                   
> -----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                   
> Cmdlet          Select-String                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
> ```

They don't work exactly the same though or take the same input. `Select-String` is generally better for use in PowerShell, but check the help to see how it works.

As Mathias pointed out, for what you're doing, you probably want `Select-Object`:

```
Get-AppXProvisionPackage -online | Select-Object DisplayName
```

This would return a new object with a single property `DisplayName`. To get the value of the property only you can use:

```
Get-AppXProvisionPackage -online | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
```

(see also [CapitanShinChan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572317/3905079))

PowerShell cmdlets often return objects with various properties, and the stylized format you see is for display, but you can access properties programmatically without using string parsing. `Select-Object` is one way, another is to use dot `.` notation:

```
$pkg = Get-AppXProvisionPackage -online
$pkg.DisplayName
```

Comment: a bit more precise, Select-Object **-ExpandProperty** <prop> is similar to the dot notation from above.

Comment: @Timo yes true, updated. I also recommend upvoting CaptianShinChan's answer with explained this well

Answer (score 2):

Both are native ways.

Like briantist said, the regular return of a powershell cmdlet is an object, which is "beautifully" displayed. So findstr will take that output from the console and filter it.

if you use Select-String, you're trying to match the string "DisplayName", but the input to the Cmdlet are objects, not strings.

The proper way to do it, (full powershell) would be:

```bsh
Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | select "DisplayName"
```

From that command, the output would be a property of the object returned by the first Cmdlet. If you want the plain string, you should use the "-ExpandProperty" parameter to the select (Select-Object) Cmdlet.

```bsh
Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | select -ExpandProperty "DisplayName"
```